# Error removing peer1 from org1 on BYFN: Are there more files to change from BYFN than the first-network folder?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I had the following error while trying to remove org1 peer1 from BYFN. Some help?

Maybe missed changing configtx.yaml? Where should I change?
Are there more files to change from BYFN than the first-network folder?

(1)In Crypto-config.yaml, change the Template Count value to 1.

(2)In docker-compose-cli.yaml, I removed references to peer1.org1.example.com, the same as in the '.sh' scripts in the first network folder.

```
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer1.org1.example.com:8051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup peer1.org1.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"
peer1.org1 failed to join the channel, Retry after 3 seconds
+ peer channel join -b mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ set +x
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer1.org1.example.com:8051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup peer1.org1.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! After 10 attempts, peer1.org1 has failed to join channel 'mychannel' !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

Answer (score 0):

the script is trying to join channel from peer1.org1 which dose not exists you need to edit script.sh in script folder. look for function joinchannel.